# I want to change the sidebar direction using UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swipe

I currently have a menu (SideBar) that reveals upon swipe and I want the menu to slide from right to left. I changed the swipe direction to match but I'm not sure how to change the SideBar frame or animation. How can I make the SideBar come from the right instead of left?

```
    //
//  SideBar.swift
//  SideBarMenu
//
//  Created by Alexandre on 30/01/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Alexandre. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit



//Necessary if we want to specify orptional requirements
@objc protocol SideBarDelegate{
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int)
    optional func sideBarWillClose()
    optional func sideBarWillOpen()
}

//When an item of the sidebar is selected, and also when the sidebar will open or close
class SideBar: NSObject, SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {

    let barWidth:CGFloat                    = 150.0
    let sideBarTableViewTopInset:CGFloat    = 64.0
    let sideBarContainerView:UIView         = UIView()
    let sideBarTableViewController:SideBarTableViewController = SideBarTableViewController()
    var originView:UIView!

    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
    var delegate:SideBarDelegate!
    var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

    //This init only allocate memory
    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
        super.init()

        originView = sourceView
        sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems

        setupSideBar()

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView)

        let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

        let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func setupSideBar(){
        sideBarContainerView.frame              = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, originView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView.frame.size.height)
        sideBarContainerView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.clearColor()
        sideBarContainerView.clipsToBounds      = false

        //Add the sideBar to the originView
        originView.addSubview(sideBarContainerView)

        //blur back of the ground
        //let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
        //blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        //sideBarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)

        //Setup the menu/tableView
        sideBarTableViewController.delegate                     = self
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame              = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds      = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle     = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.clearColor()
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop       = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset       = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sideBarTableViewTopInset, 0, 0, 0)

        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)
    }

    func handleSwipe(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right {
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose?()
        } else {
            showSideBar(true)
            delegate?.sideBarWillOpen?()
        }
    }

    func showSideBar(shouldOpen:Bool){
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        isSideBarOpen = shouldOpen

        //The gravity modifies the open and close speed
        let gravityX:CGFloat    = (shouldOpen) ? 1 : -1
        let magnitude:CGFloat   = (shouldOpen) ? 20 : -20
        let boundaryX:CGFloat   = (shouldOpen) ? barWidth : -barWidth - 1

        let gravity:UIGravityBehavior   = UIGravityBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        gravity.gravityDirection        = CGVectorMake(gravityX, 0)
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        let collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        collisionBehavior.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("sideBarBoundary", fromPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, 20), toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, originView.frame.size.height))
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

        let pushBehavior:UIPushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView], mode: UIPushBehaviorMode.Instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = magnitude
        animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)

        let sideBarBehavior:UIDynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        sideBarBehavior.elasticity = -0.3
        animator.addBehavior(sideBarBehavior)

    }


    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }


}
```

Comment: Please give more details about what you're trying to accomplish. Are you  trying to change the layout of the menu?

Comment: I want to show the sidebar from right to left when I swipe from right to left! but that code shows the sidebar from left to right..T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make your starting frame offscreen to the right instead of the left. You'll also need to change the gravity direction.

in `setupSideBar`, you'll want to change the first line:

```
sideBarContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 1, originView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView.frame.size.height)
// notice the change in the first value (x position) 
// the width +1 puts it offscreen +1. 
// Previously it was -width-1 which put it to the left
```

then, in `showSideBar`:

```
// just reversing the gravity
let gravityX:CGFloat    = (shouldOpen) ? -1 : 1
```

Comment: Only the gravity direction..? I don't need to change CGRectMake ??

Comment: Seems like you missed half my answer.

Comment: ah hah I see!! Thank you:D